# Jfreechart selection

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

Is there a way to be able to click on a segment on a plot and have jfreechart tell me the x/y coordinates of that point or somehow return the corresponding data associated with that line?

Does jfreechart have any packages at all for interacting with the plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing the [ChartMouseListener](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) interface will provide you ChartMouseEvents when the user clicks on the chart. A ChartEntity is available from the [ChartMouseEvent](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseEvent.html#getEntity()) to give you specific information about what was clicked on.

I believe there's a demo showing how to capture chart mouse events in the JFreeChart Developer's Guide.

Answer (score 1):

See this method in JFreeChart class:

```
public BufferedImage createBufferedImage(int width, int height,
                                             ChartRenderingInfo info)
```

You pass an instance of ChartRenderingInfo which you can use later to obtain the information about various parts using a code like this:

```
ChartEntity entity = info.getEntityCollection().getEntity(x, y);
```

See the javadoc for ChartRenderingInfo for other information that's available there.